# rails 4 Controller namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-routes

```
route ->
 namespace :admin do
   get '' => 'home#index'
 end


 class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 layout 'admin'

 class Admin::HomeController < Admin::ApplicationController
```

When i first open just /, and then open /admin/ rails show me this:

```
 home_controller.rb:1: warning: toplevel constant ApplicationController referenced by     Admin::ApplicationController
```

But when i got to /admin/ at first time all work how expected.

Where problem is, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
module Admin
  class ApplicationController <  ::ApplicationController
  end
end

module Admin
  class HomeController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```